# Google Nearby Connections api vs Nearby Messages api, benefits/limitations

Tags: android, connection, message, google-nearby

I'm starting to think about a near by group chat application in Android with the following prerequisites:

- Have to be able to connect groups of users up to 250 without too much problems.
- The messages sent by the users will be public and all the group members have to receive them.
- The message will be the combination of a tiny profile image (no more than 20KB), a user identifier and a text message up to 250 characters.
- The range of the messages should be around 100 meters (~300ft)

These are the base requirements, there are other ones that are also related to the way of connect but I want to keep it clear and simply by now.

I tried to look for information of both apis but I'm still doubitative about them.
I know that the connections api has a mesh P2P_CLUSTER strategy that probably could fit but I don't have information about other things such as stability, real distance and maximum number of users.
On the other hand, the messages api seems more suitable but It needs a permanent internet connection, which is something still in consideration for the moment.